# 404 in python flask application on EC2

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-404

i'm kinda new to all this, so bare with me

I'm trying to deploy my flask app to EC2, and before getting to set a WSGI server, id like to try to connect to port 8080
the code can be found here: https://github.com/Klasyer/POBAP

I've set the flask app host to 0.0.0.0 and port to 8080
In EC2 i opened the inbound rule for 8080

When i try to open the app through the web (http://18.223.32.186:8080/) i get a 404.

What am i missing/doing wrong?
Thanks ahead for any help

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching an elastic IP address to the instance that your running and once it is done you can access the flask app running in the instance. But you should include the port number always while accessing it.

If you need the app to be accessed without the use of port number then in your flask app change the port number to 443 which is for HTTPS and 80 for HTTP. If you need HTTPS the process is somewhat different because you need to make a purchase but for HTTP it's free. So go on with HTTP by using the port number as 80

`app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
i've set up an elastic ip (3.17.30.122), but i get the same result.

about the 80 port, if i do it without WSGI i get permission denied, and with i get the same 404 not found

Comment: Did you set the inbound rules??

Comment: yeah i did, 80, 8080 and 4433

Comment: Try setting it to all traffic `0.0.0.0`